# Generate warning on specific method call (.net binary class library)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using some external .net libraries (already compiled, source code not available).

I would like to have some specific method calls to generate a compiler warning.

So for example, let's say we have the following class :

```
public class ExternalAPI
{
     public void MethodCallNotThreadSafe();
     public void MethodCallThreadSafe();
}
```

I would like that the following in my code generates a compiler warning (which will also trigger an error since using warning as errors, but that's off topic).

```
ExternalAPI api = new ExternalAPI();
api.MethodCallNotThreadSafe(); //Should trigger a warning
```

As mentioned, I do not have the source code for the library (or for some cases I do, but do not want to use obsolete), so Obsolete attribute is not an option.

Comment: What if you create a wrapper class for extenal library function calls. In this class you can use #warning directive.

Comment: If you don't want to use those methods, why are you using those methods? Just search for the "not-thread-safe" method calls and replace them with the safe ones. You could write a code-analyzer with Rosyln, but it will be pretty project specific.

Comment: @RonBeyer Well one reason is, I'm not the only one on that codebase (actually open source), so I'd prefer to have automated system that fails the build/ci instead of checking code manually. 
Second is of course the methods in question are not that obviously written as in my simplified sample (so it's easy for user to "just use it" accidentally instead of the correct one)
And yes just after posting question I looked as Roslyn analyser project, and made one that fits my need (was quite easy)

Comment: @TamásKecskeméti 'm not the only one to use that code base, so i want to make sure the property (or method) is never accessed in my context.  Wrapping it would not prevent it to be called accidently.